# On Tablets, is internal storage the only option to store images?

Tags: android

On Tablets, is internal storage the only option to store images?

I'm writing an app that gets data from a web service, the data is Base64 encoded image.  I have to save this image on phones & tablets.  On a phone I have the option of storing the image on external storage but if the device is a tablet is internal storage my only option?

The tablet im using is a Nexus 7.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: no friend in tablet also we can use the external storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tablet you are using does not have an SD card slot or some other removable storage option then the internal storage will sadly be your only option.

You can check to see if there is an external storage option present and save to that if it is available, and if not default back to the internal. This page will explain all teh available commands to check for the presence of external storage

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html.

Comment: I was under the same impression but when I check if Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED it comes back as mounted. The path I get back is "/storage/emulated/0". Go figure